# Flutter app build is completing for iOS in Xcode, but it is crashing immediately on run

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, dart, cocoapods

I have built an app in [FlutterFlow](https://github.com/FlutterFlow/flutterflow-docs), and exported it to Xcode for building an app bundle for store upload.

I have installed all of the app dependencies, Flutter, [CocoaPods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CocoaPods), and iOS simulator for iPhone.

I have set up the signing account with my Apple Developer account, set the developer team in Xcode, and registered the app bundle identifier.

I then run the app in Xcode v15.0.1 after completing all of the setup settings in Runner and set it to run in iPhone 15 simulator with iOS 17.0.

The build process completes fully without any issues.

Then, when the app is sent to the iPhone simulator to run, it shows only a white screen, and these error messages:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
```

```
[FATAL:flutter/display_list/skia/dl_sk_dispatcher.cc(277)] Check failed: false.
```

It then shuts the app launch down, and shows the thread with SIGABRT.

The first message is in regards to The Core Telephony service.

The second appears to relate to [Skia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skia_Graphics_Engine), the graphics rendering library of Flutter, but it does not indicate the cause.

What might be causing this, and how can it be resolved?

I have tried checking all of the runner settings, and attempting to run the "flutter build ios" command from terminal directly, which does not work either and says to use "Product/Run" from Xcode.

I have tried cleaning the build folder and rebuilding multiple times, without any changes.

The app uses [Firebase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebase), a subsection runner target called "ImageNotifcation" for notifications.

I have changed the build phases settings to resolve previous issues, and they are in this order:

1. Target Dependencies
2. Run Build Tool Plugins
3. Check Pods Manifest.lock
4. Embed Frameworks
5. Embed App Extensions
6. Embed Pods Frameworks
7. Run Script
8. Compile Sources
9. Link Binary with Libraries
10. Copy Bundle Resources
11. Thin Binary
12. Copy Pods Resources

Comment: Even this verbose, is it actually answerable?

Comment: I'm running into this issue as well for my iOS project in Flutter. I just implemented Firebase into my project funny enough. I've tried a few things as well including using an old build (pre-firebase) which also ran into the skia issue on launch. This makes me believe that the issue is either with my emulator (it was working a month ago) or some package dependency being updated with bad code. I'll try to fiddle around with it this weekend to hopefully find the culprit. If anyone knows the answer that would be great.

Comment: FOLLOW UP: I continued to have this issue for several cycles of attempting fixes and rebuilding. I then resorted to simply exporting the app archive into testflight, trying it on a physical device, and it actually worked on a physical device without issues, while still not functioning on the simulator on the same build. 

This is an emulator issue, and a work around seems to be trying it on an actual iPhone. Hopefully someone is able to find a way to fix the simulator itself.

Comment: Check this https://groups.google.com/g/flutter-announce/c/U6Oa3TC6BAI

Answer (score 5):

The problem is related to Impeller rendering engine on iOS. check this [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/136847)

Try running without Impeller like below

```
flutter run --no-enable-impeller
```

Comment: This worked for me on MacOs xcode 14.3

Comment: within Android Studio, you can add this flag by going to Run > Edit Configurations (or the Edit Config Settings located just to the right of the Run/Debug buttons) and adding `--no-enable-impeller` to *Additional run args*

Answer (score 4):

add this code into your info.plist file

```
<key>FLTEnableImpeller</key>
<false/>
```

then you can run your code normally. That's worked for me